# How to generate signal interrupt on a file descriptor in Linux?

Tags: linux, signals, interrupt

How can I generate a signal interrupt on a file descriptor in Linux?

Motivation is to generate a interrupt in userland as we have in microcontrollers. I'll have file descriptor for I/O, and want to generate a interrupt whenever there will be a change in its status?

Can someone tell me? If possible please give me example.

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a signal when a particular file descriptor is accessed?

Comment: This normally happens inside the kernel. Are you writing a driver for that device?

Answer (score 14):

Linux provides two mechanism for monitoring file system events; [`dnotify`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/dnotify.txt) and [`inotify`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/inotify.txt).

The older of the two, `dnotify`, was introduced in kernel version 2.4.0. It allows applications to register to receive notifications on changes in a directory via the [`fcntl()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) interface. The notifications themselves are delivered via signals. The `dnotify` mechanism is limited to monitoring changes in a directory, it does not allow monitoring of individual files. Furthermore, it requires maintaining an open file descriptor to the directory being monitored. The `dnotify` mechanism was deprecated in 2.6.13, when `inotify` was introduced.

New programs should use the `inotify` mechanism, which supports monitoring of both directories and individual files. It is, however, not based on signals. An `inotify` instance is associated with a file descriptor. Event notifications can be read from this file descriptor.

A limitation of both mechanisms is that there is no option to watch directories recursively. This means that monitoring must be established separately for each directory in the subtree which is to be watched.

---

**Example (`dnotify`):**

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* For error handling */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <error.h>

static volatile int event_fd;

static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *data)
{
    event_fd = si->si_fd;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    int fd;

if(argc < 2)
    error(EXIT_FAILURE, 0, "missing argument");

    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SIGRTMIN + 1, &sa, NULL);

    if((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        error(EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "failed to open '%s'", argv[1]);

    if(fcntl(fd, F_SETSIG, SIGRTMIN + 1) < 0)
         error(EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "failed to set dnotify signal");

    if(fcntl(fd, F_NOTIFY, DN_MODIFY|DN_CREATE|DN_DELETE|DN_MULTISHOT))
    error(EXIT_FAILURE, errno, 
              "failed to register notification for '%s'", argv[1]);

    while (1) {
        pause();
        printf("event occured for fd=%d\n", event_fd);
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
fcntl(fd, F_SETSIG, SIGRTMIN + 1)
```

Sets the signal sent when notification events occur. A value of zero indicates that `SIGIO` (the default) is sent. Any other value, including `SIGIO`, is interpreted as the signal to be sent instead. In the latter case, the signal handler receives a `siginfo_t` structure as its second argument, and the `si_fd` field of the structure will contain the file descriptor which generated the event.

If a realtime signal (`>= SIGRTMIN`) is used for notifications, multiple I/O events may be queued using the same signal number (depending on available memory). A realtime signal should be used especially when using `DN_MULTISHOT`.

```
fcntl(fd, F_NOTIFY, DN_MODIFY|DN_CREATE|DN_DELETE|DN_MULTISHOT)
```

Sets the events that will cause notifications when the directory referred to by fd, or any files it contains are changed. The available event types are:

- `DN_ACCESS`  A file is accessed.
- `DN_MODIFY`  A file is modified.
- `DN_CREATE`  A file is created.
- `DN_DELETE`  A file is unlinked.
- `DN_RENAME`  A file is renamed within the directory.
- `DN_ATTRIB`  The attributes of a file are changed.

Notifications are normally one-shot, i.e. the application must reregister to receive further notifications. If `DN_MULTISHOT` is specified, the notifications will remain in effect until explicitly removed.

---

**Example (`inotify`):**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>

/* For PATH_MAX */
#include <limits.h>

/* For error handling */
#include <errno.h>
#include <error.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd, wd, len, i;
    char buf[sizeof(struct inotify_event) + PATH_MAX];

    if (argc < 2)
        error(EXIT_FAILURE, 0, "missing argument");

    if ((fd = inotify_init()) < 0)
        error(EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "failed to initialize inotify instance");

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
         if ((wd = inotify_add_watch (fd, argv[i], 
                                      IN_MODIFY | IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE)) < 0)
             error(EXIT_FAILURE, errno,
                   "failed to add inotify watch for '%s'", argv[i]);
    }

     while ((len = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0) {
         i = 0;
             while (i < len) {
                 struct inotify_event *ie = (struct inotify_event*) &buf[i];

                 printf("event occured for '%s': ", argv[ie->wd]);
                 if (ie->mask & IN_MODIFY)
                     printf("%s was modified\n", ie->len ? ie->name : "file");
                 else if (ie->mask & IN_CREATE)
                     printf("%s was created\n",  ie->name);
                 else if (ie->mask & IN_DELETE)
                     printf("%s was deleted\n",  ie->name);
                 else
                     printf("unexpected event\n");

                 i += sizeof(struct inotify_event) + ie->len;
             }
     }

    error(EXIT_FAILURE, len == 0 ? 0 : errno, "failed to read inotify event");
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
fd = inotify_init()
```

Initializes a new `inotify` instance. The return value is a file descriptor associated with a newly created `inotify` event queue. By default, the file descriptor is blocking.

```
wd = inotify_add_watch (fd, argv[i], IN_MODIFY | IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE)
```

New items to the watch list, a.k.a. watches are added with `inotify_add_watch()`. The third argument is a bitmask used to indicate the `inotify` events to watch for. The available event types are:

- `IN_ACCESS`         File is accessed.
- `IN_ATTRIB`         The attributes of a file are changed.
- `IN_CLOSE_WRITE`    File opened for writing is closed.
- `IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE`  File opened read-only is closed.
- `IN_CREATE`         File or directory is created within watched directory.
- `IN_DELETE`         File or directory is deleted within watched directory.
- `IN_DELETE_SELF`    File or directory being watched is deleted.
- `IN_MODIFY`         File was modified.
- `IN_MOVE_SELF`      File or directory being watched is moved.
- `IN_MOVED_FROM`     File is moved out of watched directory.
- `IN_MOVED_TO`       File is  moved into watched directory.
- `IN_OPEN`           File is opened.
- `IN_ALL_EVENT`      All of the above.
- `IN_MOVE`           Equivalent to `IN_MOVED_TO|IN_MOVED_FROM`
- `IN_CLOSE`          Equivalent to `IN_CLOSE_WRITE|IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE`

The following options may also be set in the mask argument of `inotify_add_watch()`:

- `IN_DONT_FOLLOW`    Don't follow symlinks.
- `IN_EXCL_UNLINK`    Don't generate events for unlinked files that used to be in watched directory.
- `IN_MASK_ADD`       Add watched events cumulatively if watch already exists.
- `IN_ONESHOT`        Automatically remove watch after one event from it.
- `IN_ONLYDIR`        Only watch pathname if it is a directory.

The value returned by `inotify_add_watch()` is a watch descriptor associated with filesystem object being watched in the `inotify` instance indicated by `fd`. If the specified object is already being watched, the descriptor for the existing watch is returned.

```
while ((len = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0) {
    i = 0;
    while (i < len) {
        struct inotify_event *ie = (struct inotify_event*) &buf[i];
        /* ... */
        i += sizeof(struct inotify_event) + ie->len;
    }
}
```

Each successfull `read()` from the file descriptor associated with the `inotify` instance returns one or more `inotify_event` structs with the following fields.

- `int wd`           Watch descriptor of the triggered watch.
- `uint32_t mask`    Mask of events that triggered the watch.
- `uint32_t cookie`  Unique cookie associating related events.
- `uint32_t len`     Size of name field.
- `char name[]`      Optional null-terminated name of the file that triggered the event in watched directory.

In addition to the bits corresponding to the event types passed to `inotify_add_watch()`, the mask field may have the following status bits set:

- `IN_IGNORED`    Watch was removed (via `inotify_rm_watch()`, pathname unlinked etc.).
- `IN_ISDIR`      Event triggered by directory.
- `IN_Q_OVERFLOW` Event queue overflowed. In addition wd is set to -1.
- `IN_UNMOUNT`    File system containing watched pathname was unmounted.

The length of each `inotify_event` struct is `sizeof(inotify_event) + len` due to the variable length `name` field.

Prior to kernel version 2.6.21, if the buffer passed to `read()` is too small to hold the next event, read() would return 0. Since 2.6.21, `read()` fails and `errno` is set to `EINVAL`.

Comment: This answer is totally unrelated to the question !?

Comment: @chmike The `dnotify` interface is the closest user space mechanism in Linux that matches the OPs requirements. Since it is deprecated in favor of `inotify`, the answer covers both.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible to receive a signal on a file change. However `inotify`, as shown on [its Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify), should allow you to write a program that receives events as a file changes.

[This site](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-12.html) has a good write up about `inotify`. It also has a sample that monitors events in the current directory.